# Drawing using Tikz

Tags: tikz

I would like to include some shapes using tikz code in my latex thesis. This is what i have so far drawn.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[isosceles triangle,
    draw,
    rotate=90,
    minimum size =2cm] (T1)at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[single arrow, draw=blue, very thick, 
      minimum width = 40pt, single arrow head extend=3pt,
      minimum height=26mm,
      rotate=90] {}; % length of arrow
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

I need something similar to this:

[image]

But replacing the BH in the top circles with CO.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get you started. I highly recommend to take a look a the [Ti*k*Z manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\draw[thick, ->] (0,.5) -- (10,.5) 
    node[pos=.25, yshift=3mm] {$0.01$}
    node[pos=.5, yshift=3mm] {$0.1$}
    node[pos=.75, yshift=3mm] {$1$}
    node[pos=1, anchor=east, yshift=3mm] {$\dot{M}/\dot{M}_{Edd}$};
    
\draw[fill=lightgray] (0,1) -- (1.25,3) -- (2.5,1) -- cycle;
\node[rotate=-90] at (1.25,1.75) {ADAF};

\draw[top color=lightgray, bottom color=black] (4,1) -- (4.1,2) .. controls (4.1,2.15) and (3.6,2) .. (3.75,2.25) -- (4.2,3) -- (4.65,2.25) .. controls (4.8,2) and (4.3,2.15) .. (4.3,2) -- (4.4,1) -- cycle;
\node[rotate=-90] at (4.2,2.45) {ADAF};
\node[rotate=-90, white] at (4.2,1.45) {Standard};

\draw[fill] (5,1) -- (5.2,2.25) -- (5.4,1) -- cycle;
\draw (5.2,2.125) -- ++(.5,.25) node[anchor=west, align=center] {unstable \\ Standard};

\draw[fill] (9,1) -- (9.1,2) .. controls (9.1,2.15) and (8.325,2) .. (8.55,2.25) -- (9.2,3) -- (9.85,2.25) .. controls (10.075,2) and (9.3,2.15) .. (9.3,2) -- (9.4,1) -- cycle;
\node[rotate=-90, white] at (9.2,2.45) {Slim};
\node[rotate=-90, white] at (9.2,1.45) {Standard};

\node[circle, white, fill=black] at (1.25,3.35) {CO};

\node[circle, white, fill=black] at (4.2,3.35) {CO};

\node[circle, white, fill=black] at (5.2,3.35) {CO};

\node[circle, white, fill=black] at (9.2,3.35) {CO};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much a@ Jasper Habicht. This is a good start surely. Let me get down on it and refine it. Thank you once again